# How to run update query without interrupt other processes

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I want to update a table and what I want to do is when other processes want to use this table, It will pause my update query and when other processes complete, it will continue to update.Is there any way to do this?

I am using Mysql 5.5 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way InnoDB works anyway. Take a look at the [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) (multi-version concurrency control - aka record-versioning or record-shadowing) mechanism which most databases use today.

If you are doing a long update and somebody wants to read a record, what the person doing the read will see is the database as it was **before** the update started. Then, when that long update commits, all subsequent queries will see the system *post-update*. This way, InnoDB's transactions are [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), but futhermore, writers don't block readers and vice versa.

For more detail about MySQL specifics, see the [manual here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innobase-directory.html) - then get back to us if you have more specific questions. If you're **really** interested in this topic, then I suggest that you read this chapter of the manual which goes into (a lot of) detail about the architecture of the InnoDB storage engine.

The [MyISAM engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) exclusively uses a locking mechanism, but nobody should really be using it any more as it's now deprecated (if [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638284/470530) says so, it must be true!).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need for it to run in single transaction (and do you use InnoDB)? From the wording I expect the table is MyISAM and all updates lock entire table. InnoDB does not have that problem as updates and selects can run in parallel. Check if you might change the table to InnoDB - it offers this and [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

If you need/have to use MyISAM, you might "split" the update to many small updates which would finish fast enough and then run them one by one, in the meantime other processes can get some things done. But those readers will see the table in "partially updated" state.